# Drupal Html array. How to reference a changing radio selection within a fieldset

Tags: html, arrays, drupal

I cannot make this Drupal html array fire the visible property on change of radio option. I have moved everything inside of the fieldset, not sure if this makes any difference.

Does anyone know why it isn't firing?

```
function services_formation_founders($form, &$form_state) {
$form = array();
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;

$form['description'] = array(
'#type' => 'item',
'#title' => t('Founders form'),
);

$form['founder']['add_officer'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => t('Add Founder'),
'#collapsible' => TRUE,
'#collapsed' => FALSE,
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(TRUE,
  ),
),
);

$form['founder']['add_officer']['founder_type'] = array(
'#type' => 'radios',
'#options' => array(
  'individual'   => t('Individual'),
  'corporate' => t('Corporation'),
 ),
  '#default_value'=>'individual',
'#title' => t('What type of Founder?')
);

if (empty($form_state['num_names'])) {
$form_state['num_names'] = 1;
}

  $form['founder']['add_officer']['individual'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Individual'),
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="founder_type"' => array('value' => "individual"),
  ),
),
);

$form['founder']['add_officer']['corporation'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Corporation'),
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
   ':input[name="founder_type"' => array('value' => "corporate"),
  ),
 ),
);
return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place $ sign at line no 2

```
$form = array();
```

Comment: sorry, it actually is there in my code, but not on my sloppy copying above

Comment: How are you calling above function services_formation_founders(). Are you using 'page callback' => drupal_get_form(services_formation_founders) inside hook_menu()

Comment: Yes Vikas, that's how I am calling it